# Editing default Dimensions of a ProgressBar(searching an alternative way of doing so)

Tags: java, android, overriding, default-value

Currently I'm writing a `customized Class of ProgressBar` in Android.
It's intent is to be quite more customizable from the appearance, which I already managed.
Although the ProgressBars have different default Dimensions from Android 2.3 to 4.2 (for example), I'd like mine to have a `default Dimension Value` across my supported versions.
After reading the Android-Doc about Overriding `OnMeasure` and other things I ended up with addings this `If` to the `constructor`:

```
if(attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_height", LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
   useDefault = true;
```

It's working and I'm fine with it, aslong as there wouldn't be a better way.
*It would be cool if I could Override the getHeight()-method, but that's not possible, so it keeps returning the old default size, which I'd like to change, if that's possible.*

Also there's one annoying Exception in the activity_main.xml, the class can't be initiated, showing this error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "wrap_content"`.
**Removing the if let the error disappear, so I'd like to find a better way to archieve setting default dimensions, without annoying errors in the Graphical Layout Editor.**

I'm sorry, if my question might be a bit chaotic written, I tried my best to simplify and structure it.

**EDIT:**
Found the solution for my Exception ... It's a bit obvious, but using `getAttributeIntValue` is wrong, since informations like dip, px etc. are in this `String`, changed it to getAttributeValue, making the Exception dissappear, but my Question remains. *Is there really no better way to do this? I really want to change the Value of getHeight() and getWidth() ...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is indeed to use onMeasure(which I tried to avoid, but it's a piece of cake, if you try it):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if(useDefault)
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), Math.round(defaultHeight));
}
```

And my constructor:

```
public CustomBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if(attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_height").equals(String.valueOf(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)))
        useDefault = true;
    p.setColor(progColor);
}
```

Doing so you can set the Default Values for getWidth() and getHeight(), when using "wrap_content".